# Charizard Black Mega evolve

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm planning to buy Pokemon X/Y, but I want the Black mega evolve of Charizard. In which game does Charizard evolve into the black mega?

Comment: Why would I get down votes for this? What's wrong with the question?

Comment: Your question was downvoted by others, I think, because it shows a lack of research effort. Simply typing in MegaCharizard on Google would have gotten you your answer in the first few hits.

Comment: But then I wouldn't of found out that I can really get him in both games.

Comment: Uh, yes, if you look on the wiki, it mentions only getting one form depending on which version of the game you get.

Comment: It is mentioned in that way on the wiki because trading is always possible, no matter what. Certain Pokemon are exclusive to X or Y but they can be traded to fill your Pokedex, of course. @Wojtek'Charkz'Hordyniec , I just mentioned a possible reason. I didn't downvote you myself so I cannot know what the person who downvoted you was thinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mega stone that evolves Charizard into its black Fire/Dragon type mega evolution can be found in **Pokémon X**.

It can, however, also be traded over to a copy of Pokémon Y and used there.

[Source](http://www.marriland.com/pokemon-xy/mega-evolution/4934-mega-charizard-x), [more information](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mega_Stone#Charizardite_X)

Comment: Actually, you can have a Mega Charizard X in Pokémon Y as well, assuming you have the appropriate megastone, which can only be found in X, but can be traded to Y.

Comment: @Nolonar Thanks! I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

The black Charizard (Mega Charizard X) is in Pokemon X

[image]

You can get Mega Charizard X in Pokémon Y as well, assuming you have the appropriate megastone, or trade it.

Source: http://www.marriland.com/pokemon-xy/mega-evolution/4908-mega-charizard-y

Answer (score 1):

Charizard has 2 mega evolution stones, and the one you get in pokemon X will make Charizard black.